# Postgres time zone conversion need to convert to different time zone

Tags: sql, postgresql, timezone

I'm trying to get the current date at a specific time in a specific time zone and then convert it to UTC in Postgres

I was able to do it but it looks super weird (look at the end)

Let's dive into it:

First, we gonna choose the time zone: `Atlantic/Cape_Verde` as it is UTC - 1 without daylight saving time (so it will be easier to debug)

And now let's split this into multiple parts

1. Get the current date in the time zone
2. Set the time in that time zone
3. convert to UTC

---

Let's assume that now is `06/06/23 20:00` in UTC

**1. Get the current date in the time zone:**

```sql
-- 06/06/23
SELECT date(now() at time zone 'Atlantic/Cape_Verde');
```

**2. Set the time in that time zone:**

```sql
-- 2023-06-06 03:00:00
SELECT date(now() at time zone 'Atlantic/Cape_Verde') + time '03:00';
```

**3. convert to UTC:**

For some reason to convert this to UTC I need to do this:

```sql
-- 2023-06-06 04:00:00+00
SELECT (date(timezone('Atlantic/Cape_Verde', now())) + time '03:00') at time zone 'Atlantic/Cape_Verde'
```

**Why in order to convert to UTC I need to convert to the time zone I used??**

Comment: Because you haven't read the docs [Date/time](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT): section *8.5.1.3. Time Stamps*. Read that  and you will understand. FYI, this `date(now() at time zone 'Atlantic/Cape_Verde') + time '03:00';` can be simplified to `current_date + time '03:00';`

Comment: Hey, they are not the same, consider these 2 queries:
`select current_date + time '03:00';` and
`SELECT date(now() at time zone 'GMT-14') + time '03:00';`

the first one will be at 06/06/2023 while the second one will be 07/06/2023

Comment: Not sure what your point is other then you can move any timestamp around with `time zone`. To keep you happy `select current_date at time zone 'Atlantic/Cape_Verde'`.  The bigger point is you have obviously still not read the information at the doc link I posted. The docs are there for reason, use them and learn. Good luck and bye.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres has two timestamp types:

- Timestamp with time zone, which represents a particular moment in history and Postgres will return it to you in the time zone configured in your session. For example, `2023-06-06 00:00:01+01` is a timestamp with time zone. If you want to consistently know what day that was, or what month, etc then you have to tell Postgres what time zone you want that calculation for, because that historical moment may have been Tuesday in one time zone / location and Monday in another.
- Timestamp without time zone, which is a particular timestamp literal but does not represent any historical moment because it doesn't tell you **where** it is that time. `2023-06-06 00:00:01` is a timestamp without time zone. Without context we don't know what historical moment it represents since different places had a time of 2023-06-06 00:00:01 at different historical moments, but we can reliably say that the day was 2023-06-06, which is a Tuesday.

Confusingly, neither of these types are stored with a time zone.

1. `now()` returns a timestamp with time zone, meaning that before you convert it to a date you've got to tell Postgres which time zone you want the date for, hence:  `now() at time zone'Atlantic/Cape_Verde'` gives the current time in Cape Verde with no time zone
2. To truncate the timestamp to a date, you can use `date_trunc('day', timestamp_without_time_zone)`, hence `date_trunc('day', now() at time zone'Atlantic/Cape_Verde')`
3. now you've got a time zone-less timestamp indicating the date in Cape Verde; you tell Postgres that the associated time zone for that timestamp should be Cape Verde. Hence `date_trunc('day', now() at time zone'Atlantic/Cape_Verde') at time zone'Atlantic/Cape_Verde'`. Now you have a timestamp indicating the moment that represents the beginning of the day in Cape Verde, but since it's a timestamp with time zone Postgres will return it to you in configured time zone of your session as a timestamp with time zone
4. If you're saving it as a timestamp with time zone you're done! If you need a timestamp without time zone that corresponds to that moment in the UTC time zone you have to tell Postgres to give you the corresponding time in UTC: `date_trunc('day', now() at time zone'Atlantic/Cape_Verde') at time zone'Atlantic/Cape_Verde' at time zone'Z'`

For more information on the `at time stamp` construction, [read the original docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT)

You can simplify this a bit by:

1. passing the time zone to `date_trunc`, i.e. `date_trunc('day', now(),'Atlantic/Cape_Verde');` ([see docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) ) which will return a timestamp with time zone, so
2. Afterward you only need to tell Postgres that you want that time in UTC. You can do this by: `date_trunc('day', now(),'Atlantic/Cape_Verde') at time zone'Z'`